# Accepting or rejecting hypothesis in two tail test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

I have calculated the $t$ value and $p$ value which is 2.08 and 0.045 on the basis of two different samples having different number of observations, mean, and variance. Can I conclude that the calculated $p$ value is less then 0.05 (i.e. 95% Confidence interval) so the hypothesis is accepted (if the hypothesis is $H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2$ and $H_1: \mu_1 \neq \mu_2$? Or do I need to make comparison with calculated $t$ value?

Comment: Which hypothesis are you accepting? It turns out that rejecting for a small p-value is the same as rejecting for a large (in magnitude) t statistic, so there's no real reason check the latter once you've looked at the former.

Comment: If $p<\alpha$ you'd reject the null (you don't really "accept the alternative"; you might act as if it were true).